# Failed to crawling FB post in new FB layout by using python selenium, how to fix it?

Tags: python, facebook, selenium

I've used python selenium to crawl FB post in 4 group.
everything is working when i used FB old layout,
Recently, FB forced people change to new FB layout,at the beginning, the regulation is not so strict, i could used chrome extension to force my FB page turn back to old layout.(https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/old-layout-for-facebook/abmkkackbbimmdbfjdilpnfaegaeagge)
However, it seems that the regulation become more stricter, FB would not allow some user account turn back to old layout, hence, my python script failed to crawl FB post.how should i fix the code?  thanks.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
import pandas as pd
import time
from datetime import datetime, timezone
import os

path1=os.path.abspath('.') 

content=[]
link=[]
post_time=[]
like=[]
comment=[]
name=[]
group_name=[]
url={"蝦皮大學":"https://www.facebook.com/groups/958581774207367/?sorting_setting=CHRONOLOGICAL",
    "【非官方】蝦皮購物交流區":"https://www.facebook.com/groups/726230870811573/?sorting_setting=CHRONOLOGICAL",
    "蝦皮拍賣《賣家買家互相靠杯區》蝦皮拍賣黑名單":"https://www.facebook.com/groups/1665783630351784/?sorting_setting=CHRONOLOGICAL",
    "靠北蝦皮":"https://www.facebook.com/permalink.php?story_fbid=1174954179312311&id=709450389196028&__tn__=-R"
}

# 登入PC版FB，並進入社團
# chrome_path=r'C:\Users\birdie.cheng\Desktop\Crawl_FB\chromedriver.exe'
chrome_path=path1 + r"\chromedriver.exe"
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
# chrome_options=Options()
# chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
# chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')

prefs = {"profile.default_content_setting_values.notifications" : 2}
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("prefs",prefs)

driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_path,chrome_options=chrome_options)
driver.get("https://www.facebook.com/login.php?login_attempt=1&lwv=110")
# FB帳密 
driver.find_element_by_id("email").send_keys("FB account")
driver.find_element_by_id("pass").send_keys("FB password")

driver.find_element_by_id("loginbutton").click()

for group in url:
    driver.get(url[group])

    # 自動將頁面捲動至最下方抓取資料
    for j in range(1,6):
        driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight)")
        time.sleep(2)
    page_text = (driver.page_source).encode('utf-8')

    # 透過bs4解析
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page_text,'lxml')
    posts=soup.find_all('div',class_=re.compile('_3ccb'))

    for post in posts:
        # 文章內容
        content_area=post.find('div',class_=re.compile('_5pbx'))
        if content_area:
            content.append(content_area.get_text())
        else:
            content.append('No text')
        # 連結
        link_area=post.find('a',class_='_5pcq')
        post_link='https://www.facebook.com'+link_area.get('href')
        if group=="靠北蝦皮":
            link.append(post_link[0:252]) # excel函式的字數限制為253
        else:
            link.append(post_link)
        # 發文時間
        time_area=post.find('abbr',class_=re.compile('_5ptz'))
        ts=int(time_area.get('data-utime'))
        utc_time = datetime.fromtimestamp(ts, timezone.utc) # 轉換可讀的時間格式
        local_time = utc_time.astimezone() # 轉換成當地時間     
        post_time.append(local_time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))
        # 按讚數
        if group=="靠北蝦皮":
            like_area=post.find('span',class_='_1g5v')
        else:
            like_area=post.find('span',class_='_3dlh')
        if like_area:
            like.append(like_area.string)
        else:
            like.append(0)
        # 留言數
        if group=="靠北蝦皮":
            comment_area=post.find('a',class_='_ipm _-56')
        else:
            comment_area=post.find('a',class_='_3hg- _42ft')      
        if comment_area:
            comment_number=re.findall("\d+",comment_area.string)[0] # xx則留言 取數字
            comment.append(comment_number)
        else:
            comment.append(0)  
        # PO文者
        name_area=post.find('span',class_=re.compile('fwb'))
        name.append(name_area.get_text())
        # 社團名稱
        group_name.append(group)

driver.close()

# 存成 dataframe
dic={
    "Post_Time":post_time,
    "Group":group_name,
    "Post_Name":name,
    "Post_Content":content,
    "Like_Count":like,
    "Comment_Count":comment,
    "Link":link
}
df=pd.DataFrame(dic)
df['Link'] = '=HYPERLINK("' + df['Link'] + '","Link")'

# 寫入Google Sheet
import gspread
import gspread_dataframe as gd
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials

# Google 帳號登入
# json_path=r'C:\Users\birdie.cheng\Desktop\Crawl_FB\auth.json'
json_path=path1 + r'\auth.json'
scopes=['https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds']
credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name(json_path,scopes)
gc=gspread.authorize(credentials)

# 開啟並更新 Google Sheet
#wks = gc.open_by_key('1wyshxxkhsWB9hswi3_KBXgBORppE9-C3kapGNXYp4TE').get_worksheet(1)
wks = gc.open_by_key('1wyshxxkhsWB9hswi3_KBXgBORppE9-C3kapGNXYp4TE')
sheet=wks.sheet1


existing = gd.get_as_dataframe(sheet)
updated = existing.append(df,ignore_index=True,sort=False)
updated=updated.drop_duplicates(subset=['Post_Content'],keep='last')
updated=updated.drop_duplicates(subset=['Link'],keep='last')
updated['Post_Time']=pd.to_datetime(updated.Post_Time, format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
updated=updated.sort_values(by='Post_Time',ascending= False)
gd.set_with_dataframe(sheet, updated)
print("Complete")
# print(df.head())
```

Comment: scraping is not allowed on facebook, why not just use the graph api instead?

Comment: @luschn, i track and download all post on these 4 fb group into a doc everyday, is graph api support this?

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/groups-api/common-uses#getting-group-posts

Answer (score 0):

try to use this facebook format
https://m.facebook.com/....... or https://mbasic.facebook.com/.....